# strange behaviour of jquery on inputbox focus/blur

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a newbie to jQuery, while working with jQuery css properties i found strange behavior of inputbox on focus/blur.

My code goes like this

```
<body>

    Enter something <input type="text" id="text" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#text").focus(function(){
                $("#text").css("border","5px");
            } );

            $("#text").blur(function(){
                $("#text").css("border-color","#555");
            } );

    } );

    </script>
</body>
```

It goes worst on blur, as whole inputbox got vanished from there.
I tried finding out on jQuery API Documentation and some other sources but didn't found any result.
If i'm doing something wrong please let me know, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works - -
 [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Fj8XZ/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#text").focus(function () {
        $("#text").css("border", "5px solid black");
    });

    $("#text").blur(function () {
        $("#text").css("border", "1px solid red");
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want to know why my code is not running? is there any error or something.

Comment: It's all about `border-style` it should be dotted,double,solid,dashed  but that should not be none

Comment: ok, got it thank you. I tried giving it as $("#text").css("border","5px","solid","#333");

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#text").focus(function(){
   $("#text").css("border","5px solid");
                                  ^  should be set
});
```

here is [jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDJje/)

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vC3R/) -- Your on focus event should just specify the attribute you are wanting to alter.

```
$("#text").css("border-width","5px");
```

This is actually a css issue not jquery.
Since you just specified border (which is a css shorthand attribute) and only gave it one argument, you overwrote the browser built in css.

Comment: thank you, i tried it but like this $("#text").css("border","5px","solid","#333");